# How are two opposite edges of a regular tetrahedron perpendicular?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I can't understand how the opposite pair of edges(say ED and BH) are perpendicular. Please help me understand that.

Comment: I'd rather say those lines have orthogonal directions, but using simply "perpendicular" is a quite popular option.

Comment: If it matters, the diagram does not show a _regular_ tetrahedron, though it would if vertex $D$ were moved to $C$. (Doing so may make the requested conclusion easier to see, as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a very important theorem in stereometry. I'm talking about the theorem of three perpendiculars: Let $\lambda$ be a plane and let $p$ be a line that intersects the plane ($p\not\perp \lambda$). Let $q$ be the orthogonal projection of $p$ onto $\lambda$. If $a\subset \lambda$ is a line such that $a\perp q$, then $a\perp p$. Similarly, if $a\perp p$, then $a\perp q$.

Now, back to your problem. If $BFHDAEGC$ is a cube, then yes $-$ $BH$ and $ED$ are indeed perpendicular. First off, it is clear that $BH\perp FD$ because the diagonals in a square are mutually perpendicular. Also, note that $FD$ is the orthogonal projection of $ED$. Hence, $BH\perp ED$, according to the theorem of three perpendiculars.

Let's see how it is with a regular tetrahedron. Consider $ABCT$ to be such.

[image]

Here, $TF$ is a height of the tetrahedron and $FC$ is therefore the orthogonal projection of $TC$. Since $TA=TB=TC$, it follows that $\triangle AFT\cong \triangle BFT\cong \triangle CFT$. This means that $AF=BF=CF$ and hence $F$ is the center of the equilateral triangle $\triangle ABC$. From here we have $CF\perp AB$ and so $AB\perp CT$ again according to the theorem of three perpendiculars.

Comment: First of all, I'd avoid using "perpendicular" for skew lines. And then, the [theorem of three perpendiculars](https://www.math-only-math.com/theorem-of-three-perpendiculars.html) I know is different from the one you are using.

Comment: The theorem also applies for skew lines.